# Commit error after uploading data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i have a simple program that stores some inputs in a database. I use flask-sqlalchemy as a ORM and didn't have any issues until now. Due some issues, i had to save  my data onto CSV files and erase everything. After that, i uploaded the data back again using the `df.to_sql` method from `pandas`.

**NOTE:** I'm using df.to_sql to load the previously saved CSV back to the database. The idea is to recover the data that i had stored.

Now, with everything back normal (or so i thought) when i try to upload data using my usual method (filling a form)  and commit the changes in the database, i get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key violates \ 
uniqueness restriction
Detail: The key already exists (id) = (#).
```

Every time i repeat the process, the error stays the same, only that `#` changes to `#+1` (eg: from 2 goes to 3 and so on).

Sorry for my english, if you need any clarifications please ask, i'll try to edit this post the best i can.

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT 1:**
The process is adding a new line to the database and committing:

```
new_observation = Observations(var1 = new_var1, var2 = new_var2)
db.session.add(new_observation)
db.session.commit()
```

**EDIT 2:**
The model of the database is:

```
class Observations(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'observations'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.today())

    var1= db.Column(db.Numeric)
    var2= db.Column(db.Numeric)
```

**EDIT 3:**
As suggested by mad_ i tried filling the `primary key` directly:

```
new_observation = Observations(primary_key = some_number, var1 = new_var1, var2 = new_var2)
db.session.add(new_observation)
db.session.commit()
```

The problem now is that i get this new error:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: New instance <observations at 0x47deb50> \
      with identity key (<class 'app.models.observations '>, (368,), None) \
      conflicts with persistent instance <observations at 0x4ab8a90>
```

Comment: are you creating a new table or appending it?

Comment: I'm adding a new observation to an existing table and committing. I've added an Edit.

Comment: Sorry, this is confusing. So where exactly are you using df.to_sql? if you are creating an object you should mention the model. The problem is related to the unique constraint may be of `primary key`. If somebody is spending time please try to provide enough material. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, i'm new to this. I've added a couple of edits with the information you requested.

Comment: By default the id as it is auto incremented being a primary key so it starts with index 1 which is already present because you have used df.to_sql() to populate the table. The workaround can be to fetch the next value of id from the db and pass it along with var1 and var2 along with foreign key value.

Comment: Oh i see, Thanks! If i do that i get the following error though: `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: New instance <other_table at 0x47deb50> with identity key (<class 'app.models.other_table '>, (368,), None) conflicts with persistent instance <other_table at 0x4ab8a90>` Should i open another question? or just expand this one?

Comment: I cant understand. Please provide what you have tried. How you are creating the object then only one can help

Comment: Ok, i understand, i've added a new Edit. Sorry for the inconvenience!!

Comment: you have to set autoincrement=False in your id field

Comment: @mad_ thank you so much! That did it! I will write the answer shortly. Thanks for bearing with me through this issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @mad_ I was able to solve my problem. The issue presented when I uploaded a table back to my database. When I tried to commit a new observation to the DB I got an error.

A workaround is to explicitly declare the `primary key`. With this I got a new error which was solved by disabling the autoincrement property of the `primary key` ( `autoincrement = False`).